# iOS facebook login issue

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I have successfully integrated "Facebook Login" in iOS app. However there is one small issue with it's implementation.

After successfully logging in, the app should ideally display "HOME SCREEN". But instead of that app displays "LOGIN SCREEN" for 2 seconds before displaying "HOME SCREEN".

What method/s am I supposed to implement so that after successfully login via facebook app will display "HOME SCREEN" without going back to "LOGIN SCREEN"?

The facebook login code is as follows.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()     
loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self)
        { (result) in
            switch result
            {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Error")
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled")
            case .success(_,_,_):
                self.getUserInfo
                    { userInfo, error in

                        let name = userInfo?["first_name"]
                        let email = userInfo?["email"]

                        let homeVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as! HomeViewController

                        homeVC.name = name as? String
                        homeVC.email = email as? String

                        self.present(homeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Facebook just get Authorization from user and back to fetch info  , you can share your code for more help

Answer (score 0):

Inside the completion block make sure you do UI operations on the main thread:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()     
loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self)
    { (result) in
        switch result
        {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("Error")
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled")
        case .success(_,_,_):
            self.getUserInfo
                { userInfo, error in

                    // puts you back on the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 

                        let name = userInfo?["first_name"]
                        let email = userInfo?["email"]

                        let homeVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as! HomeViewController

                        homeVC.name = name as? String
                        homeVC.email = email as? String

                        self.present(homeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: perhaps it takes 2 secs for the request to return - maybe show a spinner